# navigationController:willShowViewController:animated: issue

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

my App now is comatible only with iOS 7 and iOS 8, I have a problem with this method:

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
    willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     ...
}
```

This is only called in iOS 7, the documentation don't say thas is deprecated in iOS 8 or something. What's wrong, any idea?

I'm using xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317) in Mavericks

I declare delegate in another class:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *contactos = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
contactos.displayedProperties = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty]];

// Delegate
pickerDelegate = [[PickerDelegate alloc] init];
contactos.peoplePickerDelegate  = pickerDelegate;
contactos.topViewController.navigationController.delegate = pickerDelegate;
```

Where PickerDelegate.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>

@interface PickerDelegate : NSObject <UINavigationControllerDelegate, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate, ABPersonViewControllerDelegate, ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Where is that code and how does this object become the navigation controller's delegate?

Comment: Hello matt, I have add more code to clarify my question. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not setting the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController's `delegate` (UINavigationControllerDelegate). You are setting its `pickerDelegate` (ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate) but that isn't the same thing.

Comment: Thanks a lot I add the line:

`contactos.delegate = pickerDelegate;`